# Plotting a function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to plot f in this program but I am screwing something up. Can someone have a look and inform me as to where I am messing up. Thanks.

```
import math
#x is the horizontal distance that the ball has traveled
g=9.81
v=raw_input('Enter an initial velocity:')
theta=raw_input('Enter the angle that the object was thrown at:')
y=raw_input('Enter the initial position of the object on the y-axis:')
t=(2*v*math.sin(theta))/g
x=(0.5)*((v*math.sin(theta))+v)*t
float(v)
float(theta)
float(y)
float(t)
f=x*math.tan(theta)-(1/(2*(v**2)))*((g(x**2))/(math.cos(theta)**2))+y
figure(1)
clf()

plot(f)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

Comment: For starters you read strings with `raw_input` and try to use these as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, I would import numpy and matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then, you have to convert your string input into floats, for that you can use eval.

```
initial_velo = eval(raw_input("Whatever you like: "))
...
```

Then for plotting with matplotlib you actually have to create a list of values (just as when you collect real data and then type it into the computer and then plot the single data points). For that I like to use linspace from the numpy import:

```
time_steps = np.linspace(0, t, steps) 
# steps gives the numbers of intervals your time from 0 to t is splitted into
```

Now you create your functions x and f as functions of t. They will also have to be of type list. And in the end you can plot what you want via:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(time_steps, f)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

But maybe you should also watch how to plot stuff in the matplotlib doc. Also numpy has a great doc.

Comment: for steps in the np.linspace(0,t,steps) do I just assign a number for steps? Sorry I am a total noob.

Comment: that's how it works. You could also make a variable "steps = eval(raw_input("Give the number of wanted steps: ")). Maybe watch the numpy docs. It's hard at first but you will definitely learn a thing or two.